# Meteor Spiderable failing with no reason in error

Tags: meteor, phantomjs, flow-router

I have phantomjs installed from binaries and working, accessible through $PATH and MeteorJS latest version with Spiderable latest version.

I use package flow-router for routing and flow-layout for rendering.

I have all my publishers either returning cursors (through `find` method) or returning this.ready(), through I don't have any subscribe() on page which I test nether in page template code, routes code nor layout template code.

I have Meteor set up locally (with `meteor` command for run) and websockets working.

When I visit the page, I see phantomjs process running on background, with `ps aux`

After awhile I get this error in meteor server console:

```
spiderable: phantomjs failed: Error: Command failed:
at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:658:15)
at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
stderr:
```

That's all; no stderr. It *looks* like there's non-ready subscriptions but I checked this thing thrice.

Any suggestions?